# How to set multiple selections in ASP.NET ListBox?

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I can't find a way to select multiple items in an ASP.NET ListBox in the code behind? Is this something needs to be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the VB code to do so...

```
myListBox.SelectionMode = Multiple
For each i as listBoxItem in myListBox.Items
  if i.Value = WantedValue Then
      i.Selected = true
  end if 
Next
```

Answer (score 15):

You will have to use FindByValue method of the ListBox

```
foreach (string selectedValue in SelectedValuesArray)
                    {
                        lstBranch.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue).Selected = true;
                    }
```

Comment: +1 this is the best option in my opinion because it only iterates through the needed items, not the entire listbox collection.  I used it in my own solution, thanks Phu!

Answer (score 13):

Here's a C# sample

---

(aspx)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="Red" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Blue" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="Green" />
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click" 
                    Text="Select Blue and Green" />
</form>
```

(Code Behind)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;            
     foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
     {
          if (item.Value == "Blue" || item.Value == "Green")
          {
               item.Selected = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
{
    item.Attributes.Add("selected", "selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like where [bill berlington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523990/bill-berlington) is going with his solution.  I don't want to iterate through the ListBox.Items for each item in my array.  Here is my solution:

```
foreach (int index in indicesIntArray)
{
    applicationListBox.Items[index].Selected = true;
}
```