# How to return unique index value of multiple items selected in listbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, webforms, listbox

I have a listbox in VB.NET that allows users to select multiple categories. I need to put these categories into a database and need the index value from the listbox of the categories as the database works off IDs. SelectedItems (with an s) does not work in the net application.

I have tried the following code:

```
For Each category As ListItem In CategoryListBox.Items
    If category.Selected Then
        Dim courseCategory As New CourseCategory
        courseCategory.CourseID = course.ID
        courseCategory.CategoryID = CategoryListBox.SelectedIndex
        Using courseCategoryEntities As New Eng_NWDTrainingWebsiteEntities
            courseCategoryEntities.CourseCategories.Add(courseCategory)
            courseCategoryEntities.SaveChanges()
        End Using
    End If
Next
```

When iterating through the loop the code that is:

```
courseCategory.CategoryID = CategoryListBox.SelectedIndex
```

works correctly the first time around.

On the second iteration of the loop, it goes to the next selected item however returns the index for the first selected value. How do I return the values of the other indexes selected?

Comment: try SelectedIndices for a collection if them

Comment: Any of the multiple commands (SelectedItems, SelectedIndices) do not show up when coding. I believe they would work with the desktop application. I have not found a way to call them in my web application.

Comment: you might want to (re)tag your question accordingly to attract the right help

Comment: I thought I have tagged it vb.net is this not the tag I should be using?

Comment: winforms, wpf, webforms, asp, asp.NET etc - theres nothing in the question to indicate this is a web app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set multiple selections in ASP.NET ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071407/how-to-set-multiple-selections-in-asp-net-listbox)

Comment: @Plutonix You could be correct it is a possible duplicate. I was playing with how to deselect items and fixed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what ID you need to pass to your database. If it is truly the index of the ListItem in the ListBox, then you would use:

```
courseCategory.CategoryID = CategoryListBox.Items.IndexOf(category);
```

That may not be the best approach however. Maybe the order of the ListItems changes, messing up your indexes. You probably want to store the actual CategoryID on each ListItem. The `Value` property works well for that. You set the column you want as the `DataValueField` like so:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="CategoryListBox" runat="server"
    DataValueField="CategoryID "></asp:ListBox>
```

So as you are looping through each ListItem in the ListBox and checking if it is selected, just use it's `Value` property.

```
For Each category As ListItem In CategoryListBox.Items
    If category.Selected Then
        Dim courseCategory As New CourseCategory
        courseCategory.CourseID = course.ID
        courseCategory.CategoryID = category.Value;
        Using courseCategoryEntities As New Eng_NWDTrainingWebsiteEntities
            courseCategoryEntities.CourseCategories.Add(courseCategory)
            courseCategoryEntities.SaveChanges()
        End Using
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This seems like a much more elegant solution. If the indices ever get changed though, current data in the database becomes corrupted.

Comment: Your first bit of code was exactly what I was looking for I could not figure out how to call the index of the category variable to save me. I understand the dangers of changing the indexes, but as long as the categories are maintained database side the index of the listitem +1 is the index of the category in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code by deselecting the item in the listbox after it was successfully saved.

```
   End Using
category.Selected = False
End If
```

This solved my problem.